# How to get category pages to look like a certain archive page?

Tags: php, functions, wp-query

I'm not sure if this question has been answered, I'm not sure of how i should have even worded this question but...

I have a custom post type called videos and the style of the archive is different from the category archive.

For this post type i have the category Video and with sub/sub categories; for example:

Video
-Music Video
--The Artist Group
--The Artist as Solo
-Interviews
-Performances
--The Artist Group
--The Artist as Solo
-Other

Now how do I get those categories to have the same style as the Video Post Type Archive without having to create a different php file for each category.

Or would I have to create a php file for the video category? but if I had to do that then how would i get those categories to take the style of that archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with [a filter on `category_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy). This would go in your theme's `functions.php` file. See the comments in the code for an explanation of what it's doing:

```
function video_category_archive( $template = '' ){
    // your parent video category ID
    // ( change this to your actual video category ID )
    $video_cat_id = 42;
    // get the ID of the current category being viewed
    $cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
    // get the IDs of the ancestors of this category
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $cat_id, 'category' );
    // if this category is a child of the video category,
    // or if this is the parent video category,
    // load the post type archive template
    // instead of the normal category template
    // ( change archive-video.php to the name of the template you want to load )
    if( in_array ( $video_cat_id, $ancestors )
        || $cat_id == $video_cat_id ){
        $template = locate_template( array( 'archive-video.php' ) );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'video_category_archive' );
```